# ExtJS4 & Symfony 2

Tags: extjs, symfony, extjs4

I have to mix up Symfony2 and ExtJS4. All views need to be render with ExtJS, no twig.

All the application is in a secured area, only members will be able to access it.

When an user launch the application, main viewport is displayed with login form. After connecting, the entire app is displayed.

In facts, the / route need to display viewport. It will call an ajax request to check if user is connected.

if yes, launch the app
if not, show the login form

And I don't know how to do that, the / action in my controller wait for response and I only want to launch javascript.

EDIT : the login form must be made with ExtJS.

security.yml

```
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/login$
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
```

and the loginAction

```
    public function loginAction()
    {
        if ($this->get('request')->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $this->get('request')->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = $this->get('request')->getSession()->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        $json = json_encode(array(
            'username' => $this->get('request')->getSession()->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
        $response = new Response($json);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Err, so what's the problem and what have you tried? Code please.

Comment: edited with security and login action

Answer (score 2):

Process should be -

1. Make an ajax call to login_check
2. Read the json response into an object and check whatever variable is set to denote success or failure
3. If the user isn't logged in, show the login window
4. In the click event of the login button, make another ajax call to log them in
5. If they authenticate, return a variable to notify via json, and show the app, if not give them a hint as to what went wrong in a message.

-

```
var login = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    id: 'login',
    height: 200,
    width: 350,
    layout: 'anchor',
    modal: true,
    title: 'Welcome, Please Login',
    items: [
        this.username = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
            fieldLabel: 'Username'
        }),
        this.password = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
            fieldLabel: 'Password'
        }),
        this.submit = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
            text: 'Login'
        })
    ]
});

login.submit.on('click', function (btn, e, eOpts) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        scope: this,
        params: {
            username: login.username.getValue(),
            password: login.password.getValue()
        },
        url: 'yoursite/login',
        success: function(response, opts) {
            var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            if (obj.logged_in === true) {
                //Show App
            } else {
                //Display error message
            }
        }
    });
});

Ext.Ajax.request({
    scope: this,
    url: 'yoursite/login_check',
    success: function(response, opts) {
        var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        if (obj.username === null) {
            //Show Login window
            login.show();
        } else {
            //Logic to show app if logged in
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: yes but in fact /login should be the url which returns json for the form.load() function, to retrieve the last username used. And /login_check should be the url of the form submit.

But if I reach the root of my site, symfony handles the login part before extjs loading. So /login is call before I can call an ajax.

Comment: So are you trying to find a way to decide whether or not to show the login form?  The above approach definitely should work for that since it only shows the login form after checking if you are logged in or not.  I might need a clearer explanation of your problem, architecture, and restraints to help any more since I don't quite grasp what's going on for you.